# Difference between BLOCK foo ... END and MACRO foo BLOCK .. END

Tags: template-toolkit

What's the difference between

```
MACRO foo BLOCK
...
END
```

and

```
BLOCK foo
...
END
```

?

Historically I've always used the latter but have come to a new shop where they seem to have always used the former, and was wondering what the difference was.

Answer (score 2):

A `MACRO` block is effectively a function, that gets re-evaluated every time it is called, and any variables passed are local to the macro. A named block is either static, or is called via `PROCESS` or `INCLUDE`, where the usual caveats about variable scope apply.

e.g.

```
MACRO foo (arg1, arg2) BLOCK;
    ... do something with arg1 and arg2
END;

...

Foo is a [% foo(bar,baz) %]
```

versus

```
BLOCK foo
    ... do something with arg1 and arg2
END;

...

Foo is a [% PROCESS foo arg1=bar arg2=baz %]
```

Long story short, `MACRO` syntax is a lot less verbose, particularly for code that looks and behaves like a function call.

This is [fairly well documented in the fine manual](http://template-toolkit.org/docs/manual/Directives.html#section_MACRO).